# How to return JSON_ARRAY using an GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, json, group-concat

I've try return json object using "concat" and "group_concat" functions.
Problem is that I need to use group_concat but I want to have a valid JSON structure. What I do wrong?

1. {"a":"a", "b": "b", "id": null}
2. [{"id": "123"}]

...

```
SELECT JSON_REPLACE((
                  SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
                             'a', 'a',
                             'b', 'b',
                             'id', null
                           )), '$.id', (
                  SELECT CONCAT(
                             '[', group_concat(JSON_OBJECT(
                          'id',
                          '123')),
                             ']'))
     )
```

result: `{"a": "a", "b": "b", "id": "[{\"id\": \"123\"}]"}`

expected: `{"a": "a", "b": "b", "id": [{"id": "123"}]}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extra `CAST`ing `AS JSON` for the third argument of `JSON_REPLACE` fixes the issue :

```
SELECT JSON_REPLACE((
                  SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
                             'a', 'a',
                             'b', 'b',
                             'id', null
                           )), '$.id', 
                         CAST( CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(
                                            JSON_OBJECT('id', '123')),
                                      ']') AS JSON )) as "Result JSON"
```

| Result : |
| --- |

```json
{
  "a": "a",
  "b": "b",
  "id": [
    {
      "id": "123"
    }
  ]
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=32809f263fe93f36e5b8dc89f22da380)</kbd>

Comment: but did you examine the resulting syntax after and before applying that ? Please consider the [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cd9ce64160a0a8d9ae85cf16d06539f7)

Comment: You are right; Due to group_concat, it is getting converted to string and thus this double quote issue. +1

Comment: It was very helpful. I spent a lot of hours tried to resolve this issue. Thanks for involvement.

Answer (score 2):

this is what you need `JSON_ARRAYAGG`

```
  SELECT JSON_REPLACE((SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
                             'a', 'a',
                             'b', 'b',
                             'id', null
                           )), '$.id', 
            (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id','123')))           
  )
```

if not using `JSON_ARRAYAGG`

```
  SELECT JSON_REPLACE((SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
                             'a', 'a',
                             'b', 'b',
                             'id', null
                           ))
            , '$.id'
            ,  (SELECT JSON_ARRAY(CAST(group_concat(JSON_OBJECT('id','123')) as json)))
   )
```

Comment: I forget to mention that is not possible I use Amazon aurora MySQL and my version doesn't have this function

Comment: yes. JSON_ARRAY is available. if I change without using "group_concat" function I get "subquery return more than 1 row".

Comment: you don't need subquery, remove select on the 2nd column

Comment: Is the main issue. In production code I have subquery and I need unjumble this JSON together. And the second subquery will return couple rows.

Comment: It was very helpful. I spent a lot of hours tried to resolve this issue. Thanks for involvement.

Comment: your welcome, it took me only 2 minutes solving your problem. please be considerate accepting answers next time.

Comment: For those using MySql on Aurora - Aurora 2.10.1 clusters support JSON_ARRAYAGG.